# Insert data from a CTE into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following statement and I want to insert the result into a table with the same columns:

```
with Salary as    
(   
    select 
        a.id, a.name, a.Netsalary, a.final_sal 
    from
       (select * from worker) a
    left join 
       (select * from Discount) b on a.id = b.id
)    
select 
    *, Netsalary / final_sal SalPer  
from 
    Salary
```

Comment: What is the structure of the table into which you want to do the insert, and which columns do you want to insert?

Comment: Just `insert into table select cols from salary`

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN TRAN

--You need to put the CTE first and then combine the INSERT INTO
--with your select statement.
--Also, the "AS" keyword following the CTE's name is not optional:

with Salary as
(
select a.id,a.name,a.Netsalary ,a.final_sal
from
(select * from worker) a
left join
(select * from Discount ) b on a.id = b.id
)
INSERT INTO Table_Name (
id,
name,
Netsalary,
final_sal
)  
SELECT * FROM Salary
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a good reason to use a CTE, maybe not. I'd rather not.
try this

```
    insert into tablename
    select 
        a.id, 
        a.name, 
        a.Netsalary, 
        a.final_sal , 
        a.Netsalary / a.final_sal as SalPer 
    from
        worker a
        left join Discount b on a.id = b.id
    where 1=1
        and filterconditions
        and filterconditions
        and filterconditions
```